# How to use angularjs search filter in table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using [this](https://github.com/samu/angular-table) for pagination in my tables. The library uses `ng-repeat` in its directive and creates its own array from the array I pass to it.

I can't use the search filter provided by angularjs since the library does the `ng-repeat` with its own array(from my array).

Is there any way that I can use the search filter while using this library.

This is what the `table` looks like(the way the library expects)

```
<table at-table at-list="myarray" at-paginated at-config="tableConfig">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th class="text-center" at-attribute="index">Sl No</th>
         <th class="text-center" at-attribute="vendor_name">Vendor Name</th>
         <th class="text-center" at-attribute="email_id">EmailId</th>
      <tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td class="text-center" class="text-center" at-attribute="index">{{calculateIndex($index)}}</td>
         <td class="text-center" at-sortable at-implicit at-attribute="vendor_name"></td>
         <td class="text-center" at-sortable at-implicit at-attribute="email_id"></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<div>
   <at-pagination at-config="tableConfig" at-list="myarray"></at-pagination>
</div>
```

I do not use `ng-repeat` in my tables. The library does it.

The `at-list` above is how it takes my array and uses it to create its own array that contains only the rows displayed.

How do I use angularjs search filter?

**Edit** I changed the html in the library and added a `item in libraryArray | filter:searchText` and it works, but since the library's array only contains the rows currently displayed, it searches and displays only those in current page(of pagination)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ng module: $filter.

You can find this [link](http://samu.github.io/angular-table/examples/examples.html) useful.

(click on "Interactive Example")

Comment: hey, thanks. i should have seen that. i will accept your answer. but i have many tables in a page. im trying to write a common function that takes both original and filtered array. i am assigning the filtered array to the parameter itself instead of assigning to the `$scope` array. it does not work. can you tell me how i can use a common function

Comment: nvm.. i did this and it worked.`$scope[filteredList] = $filter("filter")(originalList, $scope.searchText);` while passing the array name in the html

Answer (score 0):

A great library for pagination, filtering and sorting all of which is implemented very quickly and easily is ngTable, here's a link:

[NPM Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-table)

[API and short tutorial](http://ng-table.com/#/)